# Entity framework SQL and SQLite mixed up : ModelValidationException

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, entity-framework, xamarin

I am facing a problem with entity framework. I managed to narrowed it down.

I have a web project (Asp.net MVC 5 with entity framework 6 for SQL). I create a simple test project that does this (it references just the web project and the required Entity Framework nugets) :

```
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        context.Database.Delete();
        context.Database.Create();
    }
```

**Everything works fine**. Now, I have a Xamarin project with SQLite. I don't use Entity framework in this project. I'd like to reference it in my test project to test the interaction between the mobile code and the website code.
As soon as I reference the Xamarin Project, the test fails with this

```
    Test method Tests.UnitTest1.DbTest2 threw exception: 
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Website.Models.ApplicationDbContext.xxx: : EntityType 'Xx' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
xxxs: EntityType: EntitySet 'xxxs' is based on type 'Xx' that has no keys defined.
```

To summary, i have 3 projects:

- Web project (with Entity Framework 6 for SQL)
- Unit test project
- Xamarin Project with SQLite

If the unit test does **not** reference the Xamarin project. The test is ok.

If the unit test references the Xamarin projects. The test fails.

The model is ok as it works if I don't reference the Xamarin project with Sqlite. Nevertheless, here it is.

```
public class Xx
{
    public Xx()
    {
    }
    
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    
    [UIHint("UserProfile")]
    [JsonIgnore] 
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    
}
```

Comment: "test the interaction between the mobile code and the website code" - this is not unit testing

Comment: @Jason This is more like behaviour driven testing.